# Недопустимое число индексов для этого типа cli::array

Tags: c++-cli

При присваивании матрице целочисленной переменной в объявлении матрице возникает ошибка: **недопустимое число индексов для этого типа cli::array:**

```
 matrix[i][j] = value;
```

Не пойму, как исправить данную ошибку. Инициализация двумерного массива была в главной функции, в функции FillMatrix происходит её заполнение с проверкой на то, что пользователь ввел целочисленный элемент.

```
#include "pch.h"
using namespace System;

void FillMatrix(array<array<int, 2>^>^ matrix, int rows, int cols)
{
    Console::WriteLine("Введите значения для матрицы ({0}x{1}):", rows, cols);

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            int value;
            Console::Write("Элемент [{0}][{1}]: ", i, j);
            if (Int32::TryParse(Console::ReadLine(), value))
            {
                matrix[i][j] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                Console::WriteLine("Ошибка ввода. Пожалуйста, введите целое число.");
                j--; // возвращаемся на предыдущую позицию
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(array<System::String^>^ args)
{
   
        const int rows = 4;
        const int cols = 6;
        int P;

        array<array<int, 2>^>^ W = gcnew array<array<int, 2>^>(rows);
        array<array<int, 2>^>^ Z = gcnew array<array<int, 2>^>(rows);

        FillMatrix(W, rows, cols);
        FillMatrix(Z, rows, cols);

    return 0;

}
```

Буду очень благодарен, если поможете в решении данной проблемы

Comment: Непонятно. Почему у вас матрица — это массив двумерных массивов?

Comment: Потому что мне нужно создать эту самую матрицу, используя многомерный массив. А мне даже не передать целочисленные элементы в него по вышеуказанной причине…

Comment: Это понятно, а зачем вам целый массив этих самых многомерных (в вашем случае двумерных) массивов?